# clear dialog box JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried many things but it's not working, i have a Wizard into a dialog box and when i submit the form and reopen the dialog i found it in the last statues with the last data this is my code :

```
     <p:wizard id="wizForNewIssue" widgetVar="wizNewIsssue"
        flowListener="#{managedBeanProjects.onFlowProcess}"
        style="width:100%;">

        <p:tab id="personal" title="Details">
           <p:panel style="width:800px;height:200px">
              <h:messages errorClass="error" />
              <h:panelGrid id="new0" columns="3">
                                                    ........... 
                   </h:panelGrid>
              <f:facet name="footer">
                 <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{managedBeanProjects.skip}" />
              </f:facet>
           </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="version" title="Version Details">
           <p:panel style="width:800px;height:200px">
              ............
           </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="goConfirm" title="Confirmation">
           <p:panel style="width:800px;height:200px">

              <h:panelGrid id="final" columns="4">
                                                 .............                  
              </h:panelGrid>

              <f:facet name="footer">
                 <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                    update=":form1:growl :form1:dialogNewIssue "
                    actionListener="#{managedBeanProjects.newIssue}"
                    oncomplete="newDialog.hide()"  />
              </f:facet>
           </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
     </p:wizard>


  </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Show how you're opening the dialog. Key point is that you should ajax-update the dialog before opening so that it get reflected with current model state (which you should of course have cleared out beforehand yourself).

Comment: This may help you: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf

Comment: To BalusC : when i open the dialog i call just .show() and also i have  all the update with the id of dialog and i try with the id wizard and it's not the solution.
To RongNk : i want that all input are clean after submit button and also a redirect to the first TAB of the Wizard

Comment: "all input are clean after submit": You update value in bean.

Comment: "redirect to the first TAB of the Wizard ": You can set active tab with index get from bean

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces wizard has "step" attribute to set "Id of the current step in flow", you can set Id of tab you want to show:

```
<p:wizard step="#{managedBeanProjects.tabIndex}" id="wizForNewIssue" widgetVar="wizNewIsssue"
        flowListener="#{managedBeanProjects.onFlowProcess}"
        style="width:100%;">
```

bean:

```
if(true){
tabIndex = "personal";
}
```